# What is the error here?

Tags: java

Well I am practising coding from [thenewboston](https://thenewboston.com/).

This is the exact code of him but I still wonder why it doesn't show anything?

```
public class Variables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int counter = 1; counter == 10; counter++){
            System.out.println(counter);                    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The loop doesn't run since `counter` wont be 10 at the first iteration. You'd need `counter <= 10` instead.

For loops basically operate like this:

1. execute left statement/init variable (`counter = 1` in your case)
2. check condition (`counter == 10` in your case)
3. if condition is true, run the body (in your case the condition is not true), else end the loop (i.e. skip step 4)
4. execute right statement/change the variable (`counter++`  in your case) and repeat steps 2-4

Answer (score 1):

This can't work, because the second check in your for loop is

> counter == 10

You need a loop like this:

```
for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
```

Where you define, that your variable is smaller or even 10

Answer (score 0):

Let me make you understand, how does for loop execute.
For loop has three parts

```
for(initial value; condition;increment)
```

When loop starts
1. Initial value
Starting point
2.condition:
 it will check condition whether its true or false.
If true then execute it, if false terminate it.
3.increment: 
after checking condition(on second time)

In your condition you are saying to loop that

```
count
```

has

```
10
```

Value, but its wrong it has value

```
1
```

Thats why its not executing make it as

```
Count<=10
```

Or

```
Count <10
```